# Pause Activity when the AlertDialog is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I am aware that, since `AlertDialog` is part of a presenting `Activity`, showing it doesn't trigger `OnPause` of the `Activity`. What I want to achieve is to show `AlertDialog` and somehow trigger `OnPause` of the presenting `Activity`.

In the `OnResume` I set `OnGlobalLayoutListener` to adjust the position of the scrollview based on whether the keyboard is visible. However, if an `AlertDialog` is visible then it probably doesn't make sense to keep listening to the layout changes and adjusting the scrollview accordingly, considering the "focus" is currently on the `AlertDialog` and the `Activity` is partially visible in background.

I am aware that I can start activity with "popup" style but this is not what I want; I want to use `AlertDialog`.

Comment: Why not you are using on Dismiss Listener of AlertDialog. Playing with Activity's onPause is the worst idea, and keep in mind that if you call, your AlertDialog will also be dissmissed.

Answer (score 0):

Use another activity as dialog. Then it will automatically pause your current activity.To start activity as dialog I defined it like this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```

Use this property inside your activity tag to avoid that your Dialog appears in the recently used apps list

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```

If you want to stop your dialog / activity from being destroyed when the user clicks outside of the dialog:

After setContentView() in your Activity use:

```
this.setFinishOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Now when I call startActivity() it displays as a dialog, with the previous activity shown when the user presses the back button.

Note that if you are using ActionBarActivity (or AppCompat theme), you'll need to use @style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog instead.